# Trying to update fields from one table to another

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to create a list of completed tasks, so when the user completes the task it will populate the information in another table. When clicking on the MarkJob button an error appears say " Compile error invalid use of property' then it highlights "[Job Name] ="
Below is my code.

---

```
Private Sub MarkButton_Click()

    Dim jname As String
    Dim ent As Integer
    Dim user As String
    Dim tstamp As Date

    jname = Me.[Job Name]
    ent = Me.[Entity]
    user = VBA.Environ("USERNAME") & "@" & VBA.Environ("USERDOMAIN") 
    tstamp = Now

  DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataTable, [Completed Jobs], acNewRec


End Sub

Private Sub MarkJob_Click()
   Dim jname As String
   Dim ent As String
   Dim user As String
   Dim tstamp As Date
   Dim result As String
   Dim tbl As String

tbl = tables.[Completed Jobs]
jname = Me.[Job Name]

If IsNumeric(Me.Entity) Then
     ent = Me.Entity
     Else: ent = 0
     End If

user = VBA.Environ("USERNAME")

tstamp = Now

result = InputBox("Please enter result:  Success, or error with ticket number", "Job Result")

Rem MsgBox jname
Rem MsgBox ent
Rem MsgBox user
Rem MsgBox tstamp
Rem MsgBox result

DoCmd.OpenTable "Completed Jobs", acViewNormal, acAdd
UpdateTable.[Completed Jobs]
    Set [Job Name] = jname
    Set [Entity] = ent
    Set [Time Stamp] = tstamp
    Set [UserId] = user
    Set [result] = result

End Sub
```

Comment: vba <> vb.net <> vbscript and this doesnt look like VB.NET

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you come from QBASIC or GWBASIC? Some the syntax used reminds me of earlier, pre-visual basic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
DoCmd.OpenTable "Completed Jobs", acViewNormal, acAdd
UpdateTable.[Completed Jobs]
    Set [Job Name] = jname
    Set [Entity] = ent
    Set [Time Stamp] = tstamp
    Set [UserId] = user
    Set [result] = result
```

With

```
Dim rsCompleted As Recordset
Set rsCompleted = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Completed Jobs")
With rsCompleted
    .AddNew
    ![Job Name] = jname
    ![Entity] = ent
    ![Time Stamp] = tstamp
    ![UserId] = user
    ![result] = result
    .Update
End With
```

Comment: Thanks that part worked however I not encountered an other error with the tbl = tables.[Completed Jobs]
jname = Me.[Job Name

Comment: Thanks that part worked however I not encountered an other error 'runtime error 424 object required' Here is the code with the error tbl = tables.[Completed Jobs]
jname = Me.[Job Name

Comment: You never declare or assign the variable `tables` to anything, so VBA gets upset when you try to use it.